# TeamCity: Get a whole directory of artifacts using REST API

Tags: rest, teamcity

Using teamcity's REST API it is possible to retrieve a single artifact by URLs of the form

```
http://myserver.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:85755/artifacts/files/bin/app.exe
```

How can I obtain an entire directory? The following doesn't work:

```
http://myserver.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:85755/artifacts/files/bin/
```

Comment: So basically you want to make one request and get several files in response? Cannot imagine format of such a response.

Comment: A zip file would be a decent solution.

Comment: Well, getting zip archive with contents of a folder is not the exactly the same thing as getting directory contents. But you can save directory to a single archive when generating artifacts using `*/*.html => report.zip` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [TCD9/REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API)

```
GET http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/<build_locator>/artifacts/archived/<path>?locator=pattern:<wildcard>
```

> (returns the archive containing the list of artifacts under the path specified. The optional locator parameter can have file  to limit the files only to those matching the wildcard)
>   Media-Type: application/zip

Answer (score 0):

Generally if it's a rest API it will follow certain conventions, ie:

`GET /books/15` 
-> returns the book with id 15

`GET /books` 
-> returns an array of available books

`POST /books/15` 
-> updates the book with id 15

etc.

It really depends on the implementation of the API, though.

Sometimes you can also get a list of files on a server by default via a GET request, but that depends on the security settings of the webserver. Most don't allow for directory listing by default.

You could try these:

`GET http://myserver.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:85755/artifacts/files`

`GET http://myserver.com/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:85755/artifacts`

Comment: Yes, the file listing works. But I want to download them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has already been answered on stack.
You should use:

```
GET http://<teamcity>/repository/downloadAll/<buildTypeId>/.lastSuccessful*/files
```

*.lastfinished or .lastPinned